# Making a jQuery-based square resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I have a , where each li is a square. Now the

width in the css is based on percentage of the , wanting it responsive. Hence I use a jQuery to get the same height as the width to make them square.

However, on resize, only the width is affected, the height stays with it's original on-load-value. Anyways to get around this?

Here's me code:

Here's me code:

html:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="square">item1</li>
    <li class="square">item1</li>
    <li class="square">item1</li>
    <li class="square">item1</li>
 </ul>
```

Css:

```
ul{
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}

li.square{
width: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 var width = $('.square').width();
  $('.square').css('height', width);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean be `on resize`

Comment: resizing the window, sorry if that was unclear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript shouldn't be related to responsive design. If you want your design to be responsive you can make use of [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) or, depending on which browsers you wish to support, you could also make use of [Viewport-Percentage Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Viewport Percentage Lengths allow you, in CSS, to scale elements relative to the viewport. There are 4 associated units: `vw` (viewport width), `vh` (viewport height), `vmin` (the minimum screen length) and `vmax` (the maximum length). If you wish to make a square which scales, you can make use of `vmin` or `vmax`:

```css
.square {
    display:inline-block;   /* To override the list styling */
    height:20vmin;
    width:20vmin;
}
```

In specifying `20vmin`, these `li` elements will now scale to 20% of the size of the minimum screen length. If your viewport's resolution was 1000x500 (1000px width, 500px height), `20vmin` would be equal to 20% of the height (as the height is the smaller length).

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gbvcr/).

Comment: I see, but then that is based on the window size right and not the `<ul>`?